# Is there a term with the meaning of proverb?

Tags: meaning

So basically, a word that describes passages that are like proverbs such as "the meaning of life is..." or "look before you leap" I've been wondering about this word and its sort of similar to, in meaning, to motivational and inspirational.

Comment: Is "saying" what you're looking for? An old one is called "adage." http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adage

Comment: Have you tried a thesaurus?

Comment: Am voting to close it down for lack of research.

Comment: 'epigram' is one.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for  ***[aphorism](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/aphorism):***

> - A tersely phrased statement of a truth or opinion; an adage.
> - a short pithy saying expressing a general truth; maxim

(The Free Dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

The English language abounds in **"sayings"** and "Look before you leap" is one of them. It means one should make careful preparations before engaging in something new or they may meet unforeseen dangers.

> - **"saying"** - an old and well-known phrase that expresses an idea that most people believe is true. [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/saying)